# Is it possible to ignore some output JSON properties in unit-tests with azure-streamanalytics-cicd package?

Tags: azure, unit-testing, azure-stream-analytics

We are using Azure Stream Analytics jobs and now we want to add automate tests. Problem is that in output fields are unique ids (some queries use GetMetadataPropertyValue(ehInput, 'EventId') https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/getmetadatapropertyvalue#unique-eventid-property other use UDF function to create uniqe id. So I would like to know if it is possible to ignore these unique id properties in output json files ? I could not find anything to this topic in documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/sk-sk/azure/stream-analytics/cicd-tools?tabs=visual-studio-code).

Comment: Hey there, I need to double check the behavior here. But have you tried setting the column to null in the expected test result?

Comment: Ok I reproduced the issue, and understand the case. What breaks is that in local runs, EventId is not generated in a deterministic fashion. Repeated runs give different results, which breaks tests. Let me check with the dev team what can be done here.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will wait for further information from you.

Comment: @FlorianEiden Do you have any news ?

Comment: Sorry I should have updated you sooner. I created a bug on our side, it's being triaged. I'll update when I have an ETA.

Comment: This is now a work item in our backlog. Sadly I have no ETA yet. I'll update you when the work gets started but this could take time.

Comment: Ok, thank you for update.